# How to display Ad and reward player?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ads

How I can show a screen filling ad(video trailer) after touching a SpriteNode and then get some kind of reward? If is too complicated to make, then I would like to know how to show a ad(not necessarily a video tailer)  when you finish a level or something like that, which you can click away by pressing the X if its not a video.﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION:**
>
> 1) Go on Google.
>
> 2) Search for ChartBoost.
>
> 3) Implement their framework.
>
> 4) Implement reward videos.
>
> 5) Everything is explained on their website: https://www.chartboost.com/
>
> 6) Have fun :)

P.S.: Or use any other advertiser that supports rewarded ad videos !

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Chartboost is free to use of course, why ?

Comment: Because i don't want to pay :D

Comment: I am glad you found what you were looking for with Chartboost :) Have fun !

Comment: I still have a question, I'm trying to integrate the SDK to Game using this tutorial: https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/205853276-Download-Integrate-the-Chartboost-SDK-for-iOS-Swift but when i type in the stuff from step 3 Xcode shows me a error which says: Use of unresolved identifier "Chartboost" do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: @LukasDomeisen Ask this in another question. I'll answer it asap ! It's impossible to understand what you need in the comments !